# Unable to catch exception being thrown from another function

Tags: rest, android-studio, exception, kotlin, android-volley

I am expecting the "throw RuntimeException" in ServerHandler to proceed to the catch block in registerAccount when error code 403 pops out from the server, but I am unable to catch the error... below is my code:

LoginRepo.kt:

```
private fun registerAccount(context: Context, jsonObject: JSONObject, username: String, password: String): Result<LoggedInUser> {

    try {
        ServerHandler.getInstance(context).makeHttpRequest(
            "http://www.mywebpage.com/index.php",
            Request.Method.POST,
            jsonObject
        )

        return Result.Success(LoggedInUser(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), username))
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        return Result.Error(IOException("Error registering account: ", e))
    }
}
```

ServerHandler.kt:

```
    @Throws(RuntimeException::class)
    fun makeHttpRequest(url: String, method: Int, jsonBody: JSONObject? = null):Any {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        Log.d("makeHttpRequest","Sending request!!!!")
        var stringRequest = when (method) {
            Request.Method.POST ->
                object : StringRequest(method, url,
                    Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                        Log.d("requestPOST", response)
                    }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                        @Throws(RuntimeException::class)
                        when(error.networkResponse.statusCode) {
                            403 -> {
                                throw RuntimeException("Username is taken.") //<--RuntimeException
                            }
                            else-> {
                                Log.d("UNHANDLED ERROR:", error.toString())
                            }
                        }})
                    }
       }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Username is taken.
    at com.example.inspire.data.ServerHandler$makeHttpRequest$stringRequest$5.onErrorResponse(ServerHandler.kt:75)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know all the details, but it seems that the call `ServerHandler.getInstance(context).makeHttpRequest(` must be returning instantly (even before any HTTP requests are made).

Just put a logging statement after the call but before the `return` too see if that is really the case. The HTTP request is probably made later at some point (possibly in another thread), when the `registerAccount` function has long but exited (and so is the `try`/`catch` block defined within).

Comment: LOL, excectly what I have found out just now, you are 16 seconds faster haha, deserves accepted answer.  Sounds like handling Volley's errors out of its scope is impossible to be done, as Volley doesn't seem to offer AJAX callback functions/Promises like JavaScript does.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the asynchronous feature in Volley callbacks, the Android Studio debugger has helped to confirm that registerAccount() has returned the result before makeHttpRequest() has done its job to communicate with the PHP server.

As registerAccount() has returned, throwing RuntimeException("Username is taken.") from makeHttpRequest() has no one left to catch its exceptions, which causes the exception unable to be caught.

In this case, catching exceptions sounds impossible, so I would just rather make a 
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            _context,
                                            "Username already taken!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                        ).show()
instead of throwing exceptions...